# Is @JoinColumn annotation mandatory in Hibernate?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, joincolumn

In Hibernate, to specify a column for joining association, @JoinColumn annotation in used, for example like this:

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="address_id")
public Address getAddress() { 
    return address; 
}
```

In most cases, name of the column is snaked-cased class name plus `_id`. So it is reasonable to expect from Hibernate to derive it automatically (as it is done, for example, in Django's ORM). But is such behavior implemented somehow?

Comment: JPA has a default naming convention, visible in the JPA spec. As shown by this link http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_2/jpa/orm/datastore_identifiers.html#rdbms_jpa

Comment: If you don't use it, you might end up with an uneccessary join-table.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It is not necessary, JPA follows convention over configuration principle which means there are allways some default values that you can override with annotations.

In case of `@JoinColumn`, the default column name is generated like this: `<field_name>_<id_column_name>`

`field_name` is `address` in your case, and `id_column_name` is referring to the related entity's id, which is `id`. Thus, you get `address_id` by default.

Comment: What if I need column name in snake_case (like `postal_code`), while field name is in lowerCamelCase (`postalCode`)?

Comment: If you need to override the default naming convention then that's exactly what @JoinColumn is for.

Comment: @Tobb It's a local override, which has to be repeated everywhere. It overrides just one column name. Is it possible to override naming convention itself, in one place (e.g. config file) for all project?

Comment: Not to my knowledge. At least I don't think it's part of the JPA spec, maybe some provider will let you do so.

Comment: @MikhailBatcer Since you seem to be using Hibernate, you can implement you own `org.hibernate.cfg.NamingStrategy` and register it by using parameter `hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy`. Check out [this link](http://www.petrikainulainen.net/programming/tips-and-tricks/implementing-a-custom-namingstrategy-with-hibernate/) for more information.

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to have **`@JoinColumn`** annotation. You can always override it. If you won't provide it in your code then Hibernate will automatically generate one for you i.e. default name for your column.

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What will be default name generated, and how can I override this annotation?